# Match function parts in Excel 2016

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I have this function:

MATCH(1,(PositionParameter[[#All],[Position Revised]]=$C94)asterisk(PositionParameter[[#All],[Campus Type Short]]=G$3)asterisk(PositionParameter[[#All],[Campus Num Arbitrary]]=G$1),0))

and I can't figure out what it does. I don't know what the asterisks are for. PositionParameter is the name of the worksheet, Position Revised is the name of a column, Campus Type Short is the name of a column, and Campus Num Arbitrary is the name of a column. There is suppose to be an asterisk between the first PositionParameter() and the second PositionParameter(). There is supposed to be another asterisk between the second PositionParameter() and the third PositionParameter(), but it is rendered as an italic. I took the asterisk out and spelled it out. The tooltip tells me this is suppose to return some sort of array, but I can't figure out its components. Can someone explain the asterisks to me? I would appreciate it.

Thanks,
Howard Hong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula returns a single value - the relative position of the first row in the data where all three conditions are met.

It works like this:

Each of these three conditional statements:

`PositionParameter[[#All],[Position Revised]]=$C94`

`PositionParameter[[#All],[Campus Type Short]]=G$3`

`PositionParameter[[#All],[Campus Num Arbitrary]]=G$1`

.....returns an array of `TRUE/FALSE` values. Multiplying these three arrays  together produces a single array of `1/0` values, 1 when all conditions are met in a row, 0 otherwise. This array forms the "lookup array" of the `MATCH` function

The "lookup value" is 1 so that value is looked up in the lookup array and the result of the `MATCH` function is the position of the first 1, which corresponds to the first row where all conditions are satisfied.

If there are no rows which meet all three conditions then the result is `#N/A`

Note that the zero at the end is the third parameter of the `MATCH` function - zero menas that an exact match must be found.

This is an "array formula" which needs to be confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

Often you would use this in conjunction with `INDEX` function to return a value from another column in the first row where conditions are satisfied, e.g. using normal cell references

`=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1,(B:B="x")*(C:C="y"),0))`

That formula will return the value from column A in the first row where the two specified conditions are met (col B = "x"and col C = "y")

Answer (score 0):

Well, asterisk could be a **multiplication symbol** or it could be a **wildcard in Match**.  By the looks of the placement, I'd say it's **multiplying** data from an array or table.

And, um... `I don't know what the asterisks are for` but `I took the asterisk out and spelled it out`? Why would you do that?  Was it working before you changed it?  Where did you find this formula?

Please read [mcve].  Without sample data or other information about the purpose of the formula, I will take a wild guess:

**Paste this into the cell:**

```
=MATCH(1,(PositionParameter[[#All],[Position Revised]]=$C94)*(PositionParameter[[#All],[Campus Type Short]]=G$3)*(PositionParameter[[#All],[Campus Num Arbitrary]]=G$1),0))
```

. . . and assuming it's supposed to be an array, *instead* of hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> on that cell:

> hit: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to create an array formula.

Besides the link above, here is some other reading & practice for you:

- [Create an array formula](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-an-array-formula-e43e12e0-afc6-4a12-bc7f-48361075954d)
- [MATCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MATCH-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a)

---

I think certains applications replace certain symbols (that aren't allowed in the application] with words when copying and pasting from Excel to them, but without more information about what happened, I can't say for sure what happened.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the * are real and that the formula is entered as an array formula then it should return an array of 0s and 1s.

The formula is looking for Position Revised=C94 AND Campus Type Short =G3 AND Campus Num Arbitrary = G1 
It will return a 1 for each row that matches all these conditions and a 0 for each row that does not. 
If no rows match the conditions it will return #N/A

Comment: I agree that multiplying the conditions produces an array of 0s and 1s, but that forms the lookup array, so when 1 is looked up in that array the `MATCH` function simply returns a single value, the relative position of the first row where all conditions are met - see my answer